# Cleaning up ppas in Software & Update after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ppa

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I see a lot of unused ppas (see picture below).

Ok to remove them without causing any negative effects on the system?

[image: software update]

Comment: I doubt you need source code but then I have no clue what you are doing.

Comment: @David I am doing some house keeping on the system after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04. I see a lot of unselected ppas.. Quite untidy. I am thinking of removing the unselected ppas. They are likely ppas previously used in Ubuntu 20.04 I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Ok to remove them without causing any negative effects on the system?

Removing third party repositories will not have negative effects except that software installed through them will not anymore be updated automatically. Enabling third party repositories without making sure they are compatible with the new Ubuntu version at worst may break your package system. So prefer to remove if in doubt.

*Background*

During an upgrade, any third party PPA is automatically disabled in order not to interfere with the upgrade process. Some should never be enabled again because they are not suited for the new version of Ubuntu, others may be supported and then could be re-enabled, such that the software installed through them is (again) automatically updated. Software from third party PPA's that relies on libraries not supported in the new Ubuntu version will have been automatically removed.

It is up to you to check if a third party PPA you added is compatible with the current version or not. Those that are compatible can be reactivated, the others should be removed.